# How to catch return object from BackgroundJob.Enqueue()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a method that returns a Hashset, like following :

```
public HashSet<string> RunCodeGenerationInBackground(List<string> listOfExcludedWords, ContestViewModel model)
{
    var uniqueCodesHashSet = new HashSet<string>();

    // do stuff

    return uniqueCodesHashSet;
}
```

I need to run itr background since it's a task that can take several minutes. So I'd like to know if there's a way, using Hangfire, to get the result of it when calling BackgroundJob.Enqueue()?

Something that would be similar to :

```
 HashSet<string> uniqueCodesHashSet =  BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => RunCodeGenerationInBackground(listOfExcludedWords, model));
```

Sorry for dumb question and thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, background methods don't return results like a function would. Instead, you should store the result somewhere that it can later be retrieved, like a database. Alternatively, you can publish a message (perhaps using something like [Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) or publish some other sort of notification with the result (perhaps via a REST API call or using [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time)).

But the bottom line is that you can't directly return the result from your background processing in the way you have described.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, mason ! That's very appreciated